# Fast Wald confidence intervals for a glm with broom in R

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval, broom

I would like to calculate Wald confidence intervals of the coefficients of a glm on a somewhat large data set, and use `broom` for a tidy output.

```
mydata <- data.frame(y = rbinom(1e5,1,0.8), 
                 x1 = rnorm(1e5), 
                 x2 = rnorm(1e5))
glm.1 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

Using `broom::tidy` takes a lot of time on large data, since it uses `confint.glm`, which calculates the confidence intervals based on the profiled log-likelihood function.

```
tidy(glm.1, conf.int = TRUE) # can take literally hours
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`confint` and `confint.glm` respectively do not take an argument for the method used to calculate the confidence intervals. If you want to use another method, you need to use a different function, e.g. `confint.default` for Wald.

`broom::tidy` in turn does not have an argument for the function used (or did I miss something?), it always calls `confint.glm` for glm.

To calculate confidence intervals with a different function, `broom` has `confint_tidy`, where you can specify the function you want to use:

```
confint_tidy(glm.1, func = stats::confint.default)
```

Put this together with the estimates:

```
cbind(tidy(glm.1), confint_tidy(glm.1, func = stats::confint.default))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this function is now deprecated and will be removed from broom. There was some discussion about including an argument in the tidy function for confidence interval methods but I dont see anything as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Koray. Adding the link to the respective Github issue: [broom issue #989](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/989)